# getting dimenison processing error; Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/mysql.VArBWG/#sql_aa0_8.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, ssas, ssas-2008

when i process a dimension a got this error..

Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed IDbCommand interface was being used: Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/mysql.VArBWG/#sql_aa0_8.MYI'; try to repair it.
I'm using MYSQL datasource.

i used this space on that paricular server;

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda2              64G   40G   21G  66% /

devtmpfs               16G  148K   16G   1% /dev

tmpfs                  16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /var/spool/asterisk/monitor

kindly help friends to resolve this issue. 
suggest something needful.

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

But before you do it, check that there is space left on the filesystem, since tables often get broken when there is no more space left.

Comment: thanx for the reply Adder actually i have done reppair table step before and as i have mentioned that the avilable space on the server where is table store